# How to fix this algorithm?

Tags: python

**The inputs:**

- I have lists of nodes grouped in "groups". An item only belongs to exactly one group.
  Every group is represented by a list.

```py
class Item:
    def __init__(self,ident):
        self.ident = ident

G1 = {"1":Item("1"),"2":Item("2"),"3":Item("3")} #The whole group will be dead because Item_2 is dead 
G2 = {"4":Item("4"),"5":Item("5"),} # item_4 will be dead because it's a successor of dead item (item_1)
G3 = {"6":Item("6"),"7":Item("7")} # still alive. Note that item 6 is predeceddor (and NOT successor of dead item)
G4 = {"8":Item("8"),"9":Item("8"),} # will be dead because item_4 is dead and item_8 is dead 

allgroups = [G1,G2,G3,G4]
```

- I have  list of dead items

```py
dead_items = {"2":Item("2")}
```

- I have a list of links of type (predecessor,successor)

```py
links = [(Item("1"),Item("2")), (Item("1"),Item("4")), (Item("6"),Item("1")), (Item("4"),Item("8"))]
```

**The rules:**

1. If an item is dead, all the group is dead
2. If an item is dead, its successor is also dead. However, if an item is dead its predecessor is not necessarily dead.

The goals is to give the final groups after filtering all dead items. In example only the thirs group remains alive.

My very basic attempt that only consider 1 :

```py
filteredallgroups = allgroups
for group in allgroups :
    for item in group.values() :
        print(item.ident)
        if item.ident in dead_items.keys():
            print("yes")
            del group[item.ident]
```

Moreover, I have no idea how to do the 2. Any help ?

Comment: Welcome! Sorry, but what you ask isn't our thing around here. Please review [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). "Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a specific question about your implementation. Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation, and is not a way to have research, design or coding work done for you.

Comment: I did make an attempt ! :/ I have no idea of how to push it further

Comment: That's not an attempt.  You say yourself that that's an attempt only at part 1 of your question.  If you only wanted help in solving part 1, I'd agree with you.  But you make no attempt at part 2, which is the interesting part of the question, and the part that will require some real thought.  Take a stab at solving that problem in code, and show us that. - In any case, coming up with an algorithm for you is out of scope for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I am working on it, I will update my post

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered that before doing the above loop having another loop that works through dead_items, for each looks in the list of successors and if it's there, then appends the successor to dead_items.

You can then run your loop now all dead items, successor or not are now in the list dead_items.